# iOS: How can I have my app launch the iMessage app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios5

I want to launch the iMessage app (built in new feature for iOS 5) from within my own application..
Can some one help me out ??

I know apps can be opened from within an app using openURL:, but whats the URL schema for iMessage??

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [IPhone URL Schemes](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#SMS):

```
NSString *stringURL = @"sms:";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

You can't target iMessage specifically because it is transparent in the system. So you should work with SMS instead, and iMessage will be used if available.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. but this doesn't open the iMessage. I tried with both simulator and device. Can u pls share any work around to launch iMessage in device from my Application..?

Comment: I've just tested and it works for me in both iPhone and iPad but not in the simulator because there is no iMassage/SMS app there.

Answer (score 7):

The scheme is `sms:` followed by the phone number to text. It's documented in the [Text section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/sms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008054-SW1) of [*Apple URL Scheme Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html).